# Is it possible to send color code escape sequences before login?

Tags: linux, terminal, login, colors, getty

I'm trying to colorize the console and I'm having success with the following in root's `.bash_profile`:

```
echo -en "\e]P7000000"
echo -en "\e]P0F0F0F0"
clear
```

The problem is that this is obviously only going to be kicked off the first time the root user logs in. Is there a way to get `mingetty` to automatically set the proper console colors? Proposed solutions should work with RHEL6 and RHEL7 (i.e systemd) since that's what the majority of my systems are. Note that this is about colorizing the regular console and not a terminal emulator or SSH (former isn't relevant and I'm alright with the latter being considered a user config issue).

Comment: I only know the `archlinux` trick: `/etc/issue` will be printed by `agetty` right before displaying the login shell (that is the file that contains the actual greeting like: "Welcome to Arch linux, kernel ...; please login").  I'm not sure whether `mingetty` uses `/etc/issue`.

Comment: It does but only a small subset of escape sequences appear to be supported (which are just used essentially like variables to hold dynamic information). I tried putting the above escape sequences in `/etc/issue` but they were just printed as literals no matter how the sequence was formatted.

Comment: Maybe it is not such a good idea, I just managed to lock two of my `tty`s by testing your escapes :).  Now I'm afraid of trying it myself: but have you tried to write `\e` by adding `Ctrl+V <Esc>` (resulting in a character 0x1B)?

Comment: @grochmal I ended up getting an answer from Thomas Dickey below that's along those lines. I guess I just didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put *literal* escape characters into `/etc/issue` as suggested in a comment (Red Hat does this, sometimes).  In a quick test, that works, but only colors the *text*.  The background is uncolored.  In vi, the text might look like

```
^[]P7000000^[]P0F0F0F0\S
Kernel \r on an \m
```

and the result like this:

[image: screenshot of CentOS 7 console window]

If you clear the screen, then the colors fill the window, e.g.,

```
^[]P7000000^[]P0F0F0F0^[[2J\S
Kernel \r on an \m
```

where `^[` is the ASCII <kbd>escape</kbd> character, inserted in vi using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by the escape character.

Modifying `/etc/issue` is relatively safe as long as you can `ssh` into the machine to repair it when you make a mistake.  `mingetty` prints that file before the login; `ssh` doesn't go there.

However, you might be tempted to also modify `/etc/motd` in the same way (after all, *that* is printed too).  But that introduces a problem.  In your script, once you substitute `\e` to a *literal* ASCII escape character

```
echo -en "\e]P7000000"
echo -en "\e]P0F0F0F0"
```

you'd get

<kbd>escape</kbd>`]P7000000`
   <kbd>escape</kbd>`]P0F0F0F0`

The standard for escape sequences (ECMA-48) says that <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> begins an *operating system command* and that will end with a *string terminator*.  There is none in Linux console's implementation.  You can get interesting (baffling) terminal lockups from connecting with ssh when attempting to print `/etc/motd` with those improperly-terminated escape sequences using `xterm`.  There is a workaround (for xterm, at least) in the `brokenLinuxOSC` resource.

Further reading:

- [mingetty - minimal getty for consoles](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mingetty)
- [issue - prelogin message and identification file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/issue)
- [motd - message of the day](http://linux.die.net/man/5/motd)
- [console_codes - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)